# ATmega2560 - есть ли защита от ijmp?

Tags: arduino, avr

Пишу код для ATmega2560, пытаюсь совершить "прыжок" по указанному адресу.
Но вместо этого, совершается перезапуск.

```
void jmp(int addr) {
  asm("ijmp" :: "z" (addr)); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ijmp` не имеет операндов.

Адрес нужно предварительно поместить в регистр `z` (пару `r30`, `r31`)

Comment: Что значит `пару`?

Comment: Дак, мой код вроде это и делает.

Comment: @kotleni Что за адрес передаёте при вызове функции?

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics, странно. Я ничего не менял,  но код заработал... (передавал разные)

Comment: Два 8-битных регистра `r30` и `r31` образуют один виртуальный 16-битный регистр `z`. Поэтому пару.